# Case and nested case statements in Verilog

Tags: verilog, cases

This is the always block of the RTL having nested case statements inside:

```
always@(posedge clk)
    begin
        state<=in;
        //index<=3'b000;
    
    if(rst)
        begin
            state<=3'bxxx;
            out<=3'bxxx;
        end
    else
        case(state)
                   s0:  begin   
                            addr<=0;
                            index<=3'b000;
                        case(index)
                              3'b000:begin
                                    if(ram && !visited[0])
                                    begin
                                       state<=s0;
                                       pstate[count]<=s0;
                                       count<=count+1;
                                    end
                                
                                else 
                                begin 
                                    index<=index+1;
                                    addr<=index+1;
                                end
                                end
```

And this is my testbench:

```
module DFS_tb();
    reg [2:0] in;
    reg rst;
    reg clk;
    wire [2:0] state;
    
    wire [2:0] out;
    wire [5:0] visited;
    wire [2:0] index;
    DFS uut(in,rst,clk,visited,state,index,out);
    
    initial clk=1'b0;
    
    initial
    begin
        rst=1;
        #10 rst=0;
        #15 in=0;
    end 
    always #5 clk=~clk;
    endmodule
```

The waveforms are obtained as below.

I expect the index to change at 25ns, but it is getting updated with 1 cycle delay (i.e. 35ns.)  I would like to know the reason for this.

[image: Why 1-cycle delay?]

Comment: Incomplete code + improper reset logic. You should revisit your fundamentals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be showing us all of your Verilog code...that makes it tough to help you. However, I see that
you have the `clk` and `in` signals changing at the same time, which can cause unpredictable behavior. Change the transitions of your inputs to be 2 or 3 nanoseconds before the rising clock edge.

Using `in` and `out` as signal names is a very bad idea, since these are keywords in Verilog.